# Error exporting dates from Excel to Outlook calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I'm trying to write some code to export dates from excel to outlook calendar but I get an error at the line

```vb
'Get the calendar by name
Set OutlookCalendar = OutlookApp.Session.Folders("Calendar Name").Folders(CalendarName)
```

What am I doing wrong here? The entire code is pasted below.

```vb
Sub ExportToOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookCalendar As Outlook.Folder
    Dim OutlookEvent As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim EventTitle As String
    Dim EventDescription As String
    Dim EventLocation As String
    Dim CalendarName As String
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CalendarNameCell As String
    Dim EventTitleCell As String
    Dim EventDescriptionCell As String
    Dim EventLocationCell As String
    
    'Name of the table
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pris nightliner").ListObjects("Runde1")
    LastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count

    'Cell that contains the calendar name
    CalendarNameCell = "H13"

    'Cell that contains the event title
    EventTitleCell = "H9"

    'Cell that contains the event description
    EventDescriptionCell = "H12"

    'Cell that contains the event location
    EventLocationCell = "F2"

    'Create an instance of Outlook
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Get the calendar name
    CalendarName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pris nightliner").Range(CalendarNameCell).Value

    'Get the calendar by name
    Set OutlookCalendar = OutlookApp.Session.Folders("Calendar Name").Folders(CalendarName)

    'Get the first and last date
    StartDate = tbl.ListColumns("Start Date").DataBodyRange(2).Value
    EndDate = tbl.ListColumns("Start Date").DataBodyRange(LastRow).Value

    'Get the event title, location, and description
    EventTitle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pris nightliner").Range(EventTitleCell).Value
    EventDescription = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pris nightliner").Range(EventDescriptionCell).Value
    EventLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pris nightliner").Range(EventLocationCell).Value

    'Create a new event in Outlook
    Set OutlookEvent = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    With OutlookEvent
        .Start = StartDate
        .End = EndDate
        .Subject = EventTitle
        .Location = EventLocation
        .Body = EventDescription
        .Save
        .Move OutlookCalendar
    End With

    'Release the Outlook objects
    Set OutlookEvent = Nothing
    Set OutlookCalendar = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am trying to export from excel to outlook.

Comment: Is the Outlook folder actually called "Calendar Name"?  Maybe try: `Set OutlookCalendar = OutlookApp.Session.Folders(CalendarName).Folders(CalendarName)` (without the quotes)... Also, do you have a nested folder? Maybe it's just `Set OutlookCalendar = OutlookApp.Session.Folders(CalendarName)`. What is the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: I get an error saying "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found".  It might be that I have to use the email address that the calendar is linked to?

Answer (score 0):

`Namespace.Folders` collection contains top level folders of mailboxes, e.g. "user@domain.demo".

If you want the default Calendar folder, use `OutlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)`.

Comment: I think it might have to do to with the email address, but I get the same error if I use the email address instead of "Calendar Name".

Comment: Retrieve folders one at a time so you will see which one is missing.  Take a look at the folder in question in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click Folder button, select the `FolderPath` property. What is its value?

Comment: I tried to install OutlookSpy but I can't get it to show up in Outlook.

Comment: Do you see the OutlookSpy ribbon? Do you see it listed in File | Options | Addins?

Comment: No. I tried to reinstall but got an error about .dll.

Comment: What was the error? When do you get it?